# Guzzle PUT request auth error

Tags: php, laravel-5, put, guzzle

I have the following code to save content using API from another system. I have added the credentials but it showing wrong credentials error. It is working perfectly in postman.

```
    $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();
try {
  $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('PUT', config('cms.api.backend') .'/products/'. $nid,
    [
      'auth' => [config('cms.api.user'), config('cms.api.password')],
      'form_params' => [
        'copywrite' => Input::get('copywrite'),
        'status' => $status
      ],
  ]);
  $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {});
  $promise->wait();
}
catch (RequestException $e) {
  $this->logHttpError($e->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), $e->getResponse()->getBody(true));
}
```

What could be wrong in the above code?

Following is the exported code from postman.

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('http://mybackend/api/products/74371');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_PUT);

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'postman-token' => 'e0ddcaea-4787-b2c5-0c52-9aaee860ceac',
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
  'authorization' => 'Basic authenticationcode',
  'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));

$request->setContentType('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$request->setPostFields(array(
  'copywrite' => 'date to be saved'
));

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

Comment: Could you show example request you've successfully sent with postman (no need for exact data)?

Comment: @shudder - I added in the question, please verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third argument in `\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request` is for headers array only, so you won't send request body (4th arg) this way. Easiest way would be passing this array as second argument to `sendAsync()` method. It will recognise them and `form_params` option will be parsed as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header and create a valid stream for your request (it uses [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function if you want to do it directly in request constructor):

```
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('PUT', config('cms.api.backend') .'/products/'. $nid);
$options = [
    'auth' => [config('cms.api.user'), config('cms.api.password')],
    'form_params' => [
        'copywrite' => Input::get('copywrite'),
        'status' => $status
    ],
];


$promise = $client->sendAsync($request, $options)->then(function ($response) {});
$promise->wait();
```